# Joining tables based on closest times

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to have join two tables based on others timestamp

Table A:

```
username | activity | timestamp
A          activity1  2020-01-01 01:00:00
A          activity2  2020-01-01 02:00:00
A          activity3  2020-01-01 03:00:00
B          activity1  2020-01-01 02:00:00
B          activity2  2020-01-01 03:00:00
B          activity3  2020-01-01 04:00:00
```

Table B:

```
username | clickId | timestamp
A          click1  2020-01-01 00:00:00
A          click2  2020-01-01 01:30:00
A          click3  2020-01-01 01:45:00
B          click1  2020-01-01 00:00:00
B          click2  2020-01-01 00:30:00
B          click3  2020-01-01 03:35:00
```

need to match all the activities in the activities table to the most recent clicks in the clicks table performed by each user

click matched to each activity must be the most recent click that occured prior to the activity timestamp

Output:

```
A activity1 click1 - since for activity1 click1 is the timestamp smaller than it
A activity2 click3
A activity3 click3
B activity1 click2
B activity2 click2
B activity3 click3
```

I tried multiple queries but didnt work

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server? I don't think their date/time functions are compatible.

Comment: What is **precise** MySQL version? What is average rows amount per `username` series?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One method is a correlated subquery:

```
select a.*,
       (select b.clickid
        from b
        where b.username = a.username and
              b.timestamp <= a.timestamp
        order by b.timestamp desc
        limit 1
       ) as clickid
from a;
```

You can also do this with window functions:

```
select a.*, b.*
from a left join
     (select b.*,
             lead(timestamp) over (partition by username) as next_timestamp
      from b
     ) b
     on b.username = a.username and
        a.timestamp >= b.timestamp and
        (a.timestamp < b.next_timestamp or b.next_timestamp is null);
```

This is handy if you want more than one column.

Answer (score 0):

Try below -

select a.username, a.activity, b.clickID
from TableA a
inner join TableB b
on a.username=b.username
and a.timestamp > b.timestamp
qualify row_number() over(partition by a.username,a.activity order by b.timestamp desc)=1

Comment: Will this run in mysql? I think they dont have row number

Comment: @gandalf . . . MySQL has supported `row_number()` for years.